# pandas - copying one column to another without overwriting efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have columns A and B, where column A rarely has data, and column B is completely full. I want to copy column B to column A and always preserve any value that column A has over column B.

The length of my dataframe is around 1.5 million, so df.iterrows() is a solution, however it would be very time consuming. Is there any optimized pandas function or trick to do this as efficiently as possible?

Comment: df.A= df.A.fillna(df.B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use .loc to get this done

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'A'] = df['B']
```

This reads like so: located where column 'A' is null and set column 'A' equal to column 'B'.

Comment: I can run a quick performance comparison, but off the top of your head, would you know which one is faster?

Comment: `iterrows` will absolutely be slower. The whole point of pandas is to parallelize operations like this; otherwise you could just use a dict of values.

Comment: I mean between fillna() and loc(), unless those use the same process? I'm not familiar with the inner workings of pandas.

Comment: Oh. I don't know about performance, but `df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])` is certainly more idiomatic, and will almost surely have comparable performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
df["A"][df["A"].isna()] = df["B"][df["A"].isna()]
```

Edit: the commenter pointed out that there's already a method in pandas for exactly this problem, so use that instead.